# Password protection for a file for 'write'

Tags: files, security, password, read, write

My requirement is to to protect a file with password.
The user should be able to write/edit the file only after password authentication.
But the user should be able to read the file without password authentication.

Basically, password protect the file for edit .
Please help.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible as stated

Comment: do you need the file to be available on the filesystem? Would it do to have it in some network service, available e.g. via HTTP/S and a possible local copy synced automatically on some schedule?

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with permissions, such as `644` with the owner  being `root` or another user.

This would mean that you would be able to read the file, but not be able to edit it without entering your user's password (assuming they are part of the wheel group, for `sudo` to work).

As stated in the comments under my answer, it's important to ensure that the directory that houses the file is also owned by `root` or another user, and it upholds the same permissions as the file.

Other things such as encryption would work assuming you don't want to be able to even read the file until your password is entered, but that doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: If the user can write to the containing directory, they overwrite the file by deleting it and re-creating it; the file’s permissions aren’t sufficient to protect it from writes.

Comment: That is a good point to note, I was thinking from a file-only standpoint as we're not really given much information to work with. I will add this to my answer

Comment: Also good to mention it is possible to involve root only in setting up things; "write" (owner) and "read only" (group) users don't have to be super users. This improves security, because writing to the said file is all the harm user could do upon entering the password.

Comment: you'd need to make a sudo'able utility that checks the user's password and replaces the file only if it matches. If you allow sudo'ing arbitrary programs under the "write" users permissions, a user could do other stuff too, like installing a setuid program for later use to bypass sudo and whatever logging etc. you may have there.